# Verbose name in django ModelForm

Tags: django

One field in my model looks like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    charField = models.CharField('char field test',max_length = 1024)
```

and ModelForm:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Test
```

My question is how to get, in html page, field name ("charField") and field verbose name ("char field test")?

In HTML i have this:

```
{% for field in formFields %}
    {{field.name}}
    {{field.label}}
{% endfor %}
```

with `{{field.name}}` i get "charField" but with `{{field.label}}` i get "Char field" not "char field test". Is there way to do this? Or must to write custom tag?

Comment: What does {{field}} gives?

Comment: <input id="id_charField" maxlength="1024" name="charField" type="text" />

Comment: You have edited too much. That code **does** give "char field test" for `{{ field.label }}`. Please post your actual code and the actual output.

Comment: I dont know what i saw :D. This really works! But why first letter is capitalized? Can i turn off this?

Comment: Does anyone know that about capitalized letter?

Comment: @milandjukic88: Django is open source software, you are free to read the source code and find out by yourself why the first letter is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    charField = models.CharField(label='char field test', max_length = 1024)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for field in formFields %}
    {{field.label_tag}}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

That's it.

Comment: label_tag puts html <label> on page. I don't need that.

Comment: then use just {{ field.label }}

Answer (score -1):

I would use the 'verbose_name' model field attribute and let the modelform use it by default.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    charField = models.CharField(verbose_name='char field test', max_length = 1024)
```